# Conflicting names error when installing Alamofire pod

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, alamofire, today-extension

I created an app with a watch and a today extension running Xcode 8.2.1. with Swift 3. For all targets, I want to use `Alamofire` to fire up requests. This worked perfectly fine with the iOS app and the Watch Extension, but `pod install` throws following error when trying to add it to the today target:

```
The 'Pods-xY' target has frameworks with conflicting names: alamofire.
```

Here's my podfile:

```
target 'xY' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'xYToday' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'xYWatch Extension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, just today. Apparently it is not possible to use the same framework in a today extension and in an app. See [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5643#issuecomment-233727907).

Cocoapods should give a decent error message, which is a bug, but for now, only Apple could fix this like both you and I would have expected, see [this comment by the same guy later in the thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5643#issuecomment-249175326).

Bummer!

Comment: Yes, I solved it by adding Alamofire manually in the Extension's linked frameworks.